# How can I draw \tikz \graph inside a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am working on `19 Specifying Graphs` section in the pgfmanual. `\graph {}` collapses with the text. Is is possible to draw without collapsing with the text?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds, calc, shapes,graphs}
\begin{document}
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikz [every node/.style = draw]
        \graph {
            1 -> 4 -> 6;
            2 -> {4,5};
            3 -> 5 -> 6;
            % 1 -> [bend left] 3;
            % 4 -> 5;
            % 1->4;
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

output, here text and figure collapse:

[image]

Wanted output would be the graph followed by the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `\tikz` inside of a `tikzpicture` is wrong. `\tikz` is basically a short version for `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`. By using this you would nest tikz pictures into each other.

You should either use `\graph[nodes={draw}]`, `\tikzset{every node/.style = {draw}}` or `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {draw}]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds, calc, shapes,graphs}
\begin{document}
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph[nodes={draw}] {
            1 -> 4 -> 6;
            2 -> {4,5};
            3 -> 5 -> 6;
            % 1 -> [bend left] 3;
            % 4 -> 5;
            % 1->4;
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]